# Amazon Link Enhancer javascript error jQuery(link).amazonPopoverTrigger is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I installed the Amazon Associates Link Enhancer on my website so that when users hover links on my site it pops up a preview from amazon...

unfortunately this no longer seems to be working. I am now getting the error

```
jQuery(link).amazonPopoverTrigger is not a function
```

I thought it was because I replaced my comments with Disqus but when I disabled it I still have that error.

This is wordpress 2.9 I think, I haven't yet upgraded to 3.0

Has anyone experience this:

here is the link so you can see the error for yourself: http://www.djselarom.com

the song titles should popup the amazon hover...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not using wordpress, but I was getting this error because Amazon's script includes it's own jQuery which conflicts with the one I include.

To resolve this I used jQuery's [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) method to clear my use of the namespace:

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict(true)</script>
... amazon's script here ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just changing to a different theme. This appears to have fixed the problem...